# R: rank individual column data in a large dataframe or matrix

Tags: r

I have a large file of patient data that I want to rank based on column values (without changing the order of the data). For example

```
patient<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f")
gene1<-c(500, 490, 500, 750, 550, 500)
gene2<-c(200, 470, 1000, 50, 720, 1100)
x<-data.frame(patient,gene1,gene2)
x
  patient gene1 gene2
1       a   500   200
2       b   490   470
3       c   500  1000
4       d   750    50
5       e   550   720
6       f   500  1100
```

I want to get something like this...

```
x
  patient gene1 gene2 
1       a     2     2
2       b     1     3
3       c     6     5
4       d     5     1
5       e     4     4
6       f     3     6
```

I can do this for individual columns using something similar to the below code, but I have thousands of columns worth of patient data to deal with, so this is unrealistic.

```
x <- read.csv("data.csv", row.names = "Patient")
order.scores<-order(x$gene1,x)
x$rank <- NA
x$rank[order.scores] <- 1:nrow(x)
```

Can anyone suggest a suitable function? Thanks!

Comment: your ranks for `gene1` seem wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way using `dplyr` package. This will rank all columns from 2nd to last assuming first column is always `patient`.

Also you need to pass `ties.method = "first"` argument to `rank` which means that ties are broken by whichever value appears first.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% mutate_at(2:ncol(.), rank, ties.method = "first")

  patient gene1 gene2
1       a     2     2
2       b     1     3
3       c     3     5
4       d     6     1
5       e     5     4
6       f     4     6
```

Comment: great, thank you! In my data I had actually specified row.names = "patient", so I just switched the code to 1:ncol(.)

Comment: In that case you can use `mutate_all()`

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("gene")), rank, ties.method = "first")
# or x %>% mutate_at(vars(contains("gene")), rank, ties.method = "first")
```

Comment: thanks that worked! My gene list is only 33 genes, so working that into the code is no problem. It would be useful in other circumstances (such as large gene lists) to use a code that ranks for all genes without having to specify the gene names within the code. Any ideas?

Comment: You can `mutate_at` variables starting on containing `gene`

Answer (score 0):

This code would allow you to loop through the columns

```
for (i in 2:length(colnames(x))) {
  x[,i] <- rank(x[,i])
}
```

and yields this result:

```
  patient gene1 gene2
1       a     3     2
2       b     1     3
3       c     3     5
4       d     6     1
5       e     5     4
6       f     3     6
```

Or

```
for (i in 2:length(colnames(x))) {
  x[,i] <- order(x[,i])
}
```

yields

```
  patient gene1 gene2
1       a     2     4
2       b     1     1
3       c     3     2
4       d     6     5
5       e     5     3
6       f     4     6
```